# Why are the other qubits affected by a phase flip in Shor's 9-qubit code?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, entanglement, error-correction

We have the following "concatenated" initial state in the 9-qubit Shor code:
$\alpha{(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)}/{2\sqrt{2}}+\beta{(|000\rangle-|111\rangle)(|000\rangle-|111\rangle)(|000\rangle-|111\rangle)}/{2\sqrt{2}}$

Let us say that there is a phase flip that occurs on the 2nd qubit. We get:
$\alpha{(|000\rangle-|111\rangle)(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)}/{2\sqrt{2}}+\beta{(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)(|000\rangle-|111\rangle)(|000\rangle-|111\rangle)}/{2\sqrt{2}}$

Now, I know *why* the math works here, but I can understand as to why the phase flip of the second  qubit causes a phase flip of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd qubit.
That is, when we apply the Hadamard gate on the first, second and third qubit at this point, we would get $\alpha|111\rangle+\beta|000\rangle$, when I expected $\alpha|010\rangle+\beta|101\rangle$

So why is there a phase flip of the other two qubits as well?